# 403 Forbidden Error while installing Kendo Angular Buttons

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am getting following error while installing angular kendo buttons:

npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden: @progress/kendo-angular-buttons@^3.0.3

I am using following command :

```
npm install -S @progress/kendo-angular-buttons
```

And I have provided kendo credentials using

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
```

I have registered for trial version of Kendo UI For Angular

How to overcome this issue or am i missing out something.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting from this week the Kendo UI for Angular packages will be
>   published on npmjs.com to address the many concerns users were having
>   with this distribution channel.
>
> Please remove the following lines from your .npmrc file to switch to
>   the default registry:
>
> @progress:registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
>   //registry.npm.telerik.com/:_authToken= The npm registry at
>   https://registry.npm.telerik.com will continue to function until all
>   users have migrated away from it.
>
> IMPORTANT: New versions of the packages will be published only on
>   npmjs.org.

from [github](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/712)

So you can download this package without the authentication `npm i -s @progress/kendo-angular-buttons` like this, you just need to remove the telerik npm registry.

Comment: Thank you, Zoltan. Can you help me find npmrc file. Sorry I am new to this. Also where will I find my authtoken?

Comment: you can find your .npmrc file in npm's folder (in windows it is in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm). If you set the registry you have to remove it. If you didn't then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
npm install -g npm@3.10.10
```

Thanks to jeffmodzel answer on github.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18567